# But the following day the boy goes to work for a dairy farmer. (work is a noun or a verb?)

Tags: meaning-in-context

> But the following day the boy goes to work for a dairy farmer.

The 'work' in the example is a noun or a verb? Usually work in 'go to work' is a noun: a place that you go to to work

Comment: It's unquestionably a verb in your example, because it's being modified by adverbial ***for a dairy farmer***. Compare ***I went to work yesterday*** (noun - I went ***to the place*** where I work) and *I went to work **for** Amazon yesterday.* The latter is an unlikely utterance, but surely no-one would suggest that "work for Amazon" could be a ***place** [where one works for Amazon].*

Comment: Just out of interest, how do you suppose knowing the answer to this one will help you learn English? In my opinion, whenever there's genuine scope for uncertainty regarding simple labels like ***noun, verb, adjective, adverb***, that's because those labels have outlived their usefulness.

Comment: see [work for (someone), sense 1.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/work+for)

Comment: @FumbleFingers It helps me a lot. Non-native speakers must know parts of speech to learn a foreign language. That's the only way to effectively have a good command of it.

Comment: Surely you could have worked it out for yourself with a little research if needed?

Comment: @BillJ What about this: Chen went to work with seven male monkeys at a lab. What's the meaning of this sentence?

Comment: What do _you_ think? Does it mean a place of work, or the action of working, or ambiguous between the two.

Comment: @BillJ I think he went for the purpose of working and he works there(lab) with monkeys: verb

Comment: Yes: I'm inclined to say that "work" is a verb, not a noun, as indicated by the PP "at a lab".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But the following day the boy goes to work for a dairy farmer.
Is that a verb or noun?

Contrastively, we have: go to school, go home, go to church, go to hell [a joke but a "place". Can work be a place? Yes, it can.

However, there is also: goes to care for a patient, goes to sit on the fence, goes to work at the factory, goes to work for this father. Can work be a verb? Yes, it can.

What makes the difference is this, "go to work **for someone**" is not "get to **work on time**"
The first is a verb and the second is a noun.

However, **it can be ambiguous**: "He got to work late." can be either. *He arrived at his place of work late*. OR *He managed to work (verb) late*. *And only a broader context will tell you which it is.*

Generally, "to work for someone" is a verb.

Answer (score 1):

It's a verb.

It's a special kind of verb called a prepositional verb. It has a completely different meaning from the usual verb **to work**.  The preposition **for** changes the meaning of the verb. It's best to think of this like a different verb completely.  Verbs like this can easily confuse learners.  If you see a preposition after a verb, chances are that you are looking at a prepositional verb. You can look them up in good dictionaries.

**to work for [someone]**

This means *to be employed by someone*.

Your example sentence could be reworded as follows

**The boy goes to be employed by a dairy farmer**

Other examples

> I work for my sister's company (I am employed by my sister's company)
>
> Do you work for the airline? (Are you employed by the airline?)
>
> I want to work for the government (I want to be employed by the government)

Comment: I don't follow you. I'd say that "work" has the same verbal meaning whatever the preposition, whether it be "for", "in", "at", or "with, or whatever.

Comment: @BillJ Yeah, but that's because native English speakers don't have to think about things like this, we just know what it means.  But prepositional verbs can be hugely confusing to learners because they are idiomatic in nature.  It doesn't seem to mean anything to them, and so they think they've made a mistake understanding or parsing the sentence.  That's why I said it's often best to think of prepositional verbs like they are different verbs.

Comment: Personally, I think the literal meaning must be understood at first, then, the implied/real/idiomatic meaning. For example, an 'apple' is a fruit and  then it could also mean a company that makes Iphones.